# sed not working in shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I am fairly new to sed and am trying to use sed to insert a user inputed line as the first line in another text file. The shell script I am try to use is:

```
echo -n "Enter values: "
read text
echo "You entered: $text"

sed  -i '1i $text' $file
```

The return I get is:

"sed: -i may not be used with stdin"

Comment: Are you sure `$file` is not empty? Also, `$text` in single quotes doesn't expand.

Comment: ah yes for some reason $file was empty. It did not pass from the previous script. I changed file to a direct file name and got "sed: 1: "new.txt": extra characters at the end of n command"

Comment: Sounds like the `1i $text` was interpreted as the value of the `-i` option.

Comment: am I using improper syntax or something that is causing that?

Answer (score 0):

I made this example.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
file="new.txt"
echo>$file # the file must not be empty, as sed needs a stream to work with
echo -n "Enter values: "
read text
echo "You entered: $text"
sed -i "\$a$text" $file
```

**Explanation :**

The escaped `$` refers to the last line, and `a` is the command to append.
I guess you're trying to learn `sed`, but obviously you should prefer `echo` with `>>` instead.